# How do you encrypt the databse password used by Solr's DataInputHandler (DIH)?

Tags: encryption, solr, cryptography

If you open this document:

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html

There is a really difficult-to-understand description of how to encrypt passwords to databases in the data import config XML:

> Alternately the password can be encrypted as follows. This is the value obtained as a result of the command openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -in pwd.txt password="U2FsdGVkX18QMjY0yfCqlfBMvAB4d3XkwY96L7gfO2o=". When the password is encrypted, you must provide an extra attribute encryptKeyFile="/location/of/encryptionkey". This file should a text file with a single line containing the encrypt/decrypt password.

Can someone help me break this into the steps that actually need to be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works for Solr 5.1 and 6+

1. Open a terminal and run: `openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -md md5 -in pwd.txt`.

-> This assumes pwd.txt is the password saved in a text file, so here is an example:

```
echo "my password" > pwd.txt
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -md md5 -in pwd.txt
enter aes-128-cbc encryption password: myencryptfilepwd
Verifying - enter aes-128-cbc encryption password: myencryptfilepwd
U2FsdGVkX1/zZp+RS3oim80coh80ARe8l+EF+w0La0TKRfNpZ4+smdokcV3zYyLm
```

2. Save the password entered above into a file: `echo "myencryptfilepwd" > "/location/of/encryptionkey"`
3. Save the `/location/of/encryptionkey` to the Solr server(s) and `chmod 0600` to protect the contents.
4. Add the result of the openssl enc call to `password` and set the `encryptKeyFile` path to the DIH xml file: `<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb:./example-DIH/hsqldb/ex" user="sa" password="U2FsdGVkX1/zZp+RS3oim80coh80ARe8l+EF+w0La0TKRfNpZ4+smdokcV3zYyLm" encryptKeyFile="/location/of/encryptionkey" />`

If you have done this correctly, Solr DIH should be able to use an encrypted password.

Answer (score 2):

FYI,
I ran into some issues getting password and encryptKeyFile in dataConfig to work.

When running the echo commands, be sure to use echo -n to ensure there are no EOL characters.

More info here:
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/threads/510043/solr-dataimport-handler-encrypted-pwd-final-block-not-properly-padded

Answer (score 1):

acording to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11690

> openssl changed the message digest default from MD5 to SHA256
>   (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2206) but Solr use MD5, so
>   the right command to encrypt the password must include -md md5

Thus:
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt **-md md5** -in pwd.txt

made it work for me.